# Pattern attribute value is not a valid regular expression

Tags: regex, html, google-chrome

My HTML has the following input element (it is intended to accept email addresses that end in ".com"):

```
<input type="email" name="p_email_ad" id="p_email_ad" value="" required="required" pattern="[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&amp;*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&amp;*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][\-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([cC][oO][mM]))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$" maxlength="64">
```

At some point in the past 2 months, Chrome has started returning the following JavaScript error (and preventing submission of the parent form) when validating that input:

> Pattern attribute value
>   `[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][\-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([cC][oO][mM]))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$`
>   is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid
>   regular expression:
>   `/[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&*_=+}{\'?]+(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%\^&*_=+}{\'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][\-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[\-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([cC][oO][mM]))(:[0-9]{1,5})?$/`: Invalid escape

[Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) likes the regex pattern, but Chrome doesn't. What syntax do I have wrong?

Comment: An educated guess: \\ instead of \'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use

```
pattern="[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&amp;*_=+}{'?]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&amp;*_=+}{'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([cC][oO][mM]))(:[0-9]{1,5})?"
```

The problem is that some chars that should not be escaped were escaped, like `'` and `^` inside the character classes. Note that `-` inside a character class may be escaped, but does not have to when it is at its start.

Note also that HTML5 engines wraps the whole pattern inside `^(?:` and `)$` constructs, so there is no need using `$` end of string anchor at the end of the pattern.

Test:

```html
<form>
   <input type="email" name="p_email_ad" id="p_email_ad" value="" required="required" pattern="[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&amp;*_=+}{'?]+(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9~!$%^&amp;*_=+}{'?]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9_][-a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\.([cC][oO][mM]))(:[0-9]{1,5})?" maxlength="64">
   <input type="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, using `\-`instead of `-` inside the regex solved it for me.

Comment: @RiZKiT Yes, nowadays, `-` inside character classes must ALWAYS be escaped due to the fact the pattern is compiled with the `v` flag. See [*Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287241/3832970).

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple(r) regular expression, that is not allowing some special characters like `,&-_`

```
"pattern": "^[a-zA-Z1-9_]+( [a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*$"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue in angular.
`paraInputRegex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+([+-][0-9]+)*$/);`
This regex was given error in `<input [pattern]="paraInputRegex">`. Error stats that

> Pattern attribute value /^[0-9]+([+-][0-9]+)*$/ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: //^[0-9]+([+-][0-9]+)*$//v: Invalid character in character class

It is because `-` need a escape key so the updated regex should be like `paraInputRegex = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+([+\-][0-9]+)*$/);`

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue with my application but had a slightly different approach to a solution. My regex has the same issue that the accepted answer describes (special characters being escaped in character classes when they didn't need to be), however the regex I'm dealing with is coming from an external source so I could not modify it. This kind of regex is usually fine for most languages (passes validation in PHP) but as we have found out it breaks with HTML5.

My simple solution, url encode the regex before applying it to the input's `pattern` attribute. That seems to satisfy the HTML5 engine and it works as expected. JavaScript's `encodeURIComponent` is a good fit.

Comment: @JeromyFrench There are many ways to url encode text based on the programming languages you're using, so I don't think I want to digress into all the different approaches. Nonetheless I did provide an idea of how to do it in JavaScript using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).