# Regex for date Invalid regular expression

Tags: javascript, java, html, regex

i have this format for dates yyyy-MM-dd

and generating the following reged

```
 /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]$
```

This is generated in java using the following where i replace the format with regex

```
String format = getDisplayDateFormat( formatType );

        format = format.replaceAll("\\-","\\\\-");
        format = format.replaceAll("y","[0-9]");
        format = format.replaceAll("M","[0-9]");
        format = format.replaceAll("d","[0-9]");

        return "^" + format + "$";
```

If i run this through a regex validator its fine, but chrome is giving the following error

```
Pattern attribute value ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]$/: Invalid escape
```

edit to include html

`<input type="text" value="2020-04-21" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" pattern="^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]\-[0-9][0-9]$" data-minimum-value="2020-08-10" data-maximum-value="2020-08-13"id="F112407" maxlength="10" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" >`

Comment: That regex *is* valid. Chrome is giving that error when you do what, exactly?

Comment: You shouldn't escape the ASCII dash (`-`)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca when its added to the input pattern

Comment: How are you running this in Chrome?

Comment: `-` is special character *only inside character class* `[...]` where it can be used to create range of characters. Outside of character class it isn't special and represents only character `-` so it doesn't need to be escaped (although escaping it there is allowed in many regex engines/flavors so it shouldn't cause any errors). How exactly are you using this regex? Please provide [mcve] which will allow us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt could you show me what you mean in an answer

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt but that shouldn't produce an invalid regular expression. An escaped dash in a regex (outside a character class) will just be a dash again. It's not invalid.

Comment: You can't validate a date using regular expressions. Is 9999-99-99 a valid date?

Answer (score 1):

See also: [Pattern attribute value is not a valid regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51865098/pattern-attribute-value-is-not-a-valid-regular-expression)

The valid pattern would be: `^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]$`

EDIT: However, there are more fool proof ways to validate dates. Consider using a date validation function, for example: [How to validate date with format "mm/dd/yyyy" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177975/how-to-validate-date-with-format-mm-dd-yyyy-in-javascript) 
Or use a date-picker to limit the input altogether.